# jQuery Tools Overlay & jQuery.live event

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

How to get this work with jQuery.live?

```
$("a[rel]").overlay({
    mask: '#3B5872',
    effect: 'apple',
    api: true,
    onBeforeLoad: function () {
        var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");
        wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
    }
});
```

I tried this with no succes:

```
$("a[rel]").live('click', function () {
    alert('live');
    $(this).overlay({
        mask: '#3B5872',
        effect: 'apple',
        api: true,
        onBeforeLoad: function () {
            var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");
            wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to set it to load on configuration. You can do that by adding `load: true` to the config object.

```
$("a[rel]").live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent default link action

    $(this).overlay({
        mask: '#3B5872',
        effect: 'apple',
        api: true,
        onBeforeLoad: function () {
            var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");
            wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
        },
        load: true
    });
});
```

Here are [the docs](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/trigger.html).

Answer (score 2):

The overlay is triggered on a `click`, so you need to use the [`load` option](http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html#configuration), like this:

```
$("a[rel]").live('click', function (e) {
    $(this).overlay({
        mask: '#3B5872',
        effect: 'apple',
        api: true,
        load: true,
        onBeforeLoad: function () {
            var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");
            wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/5CNYc/1/).

The overlay is opened by he `click` event, so even though you were binding the overlay, it wasn't opening because the event it depends on had already occurred.  The default for `load` is also `false`, but since you do want it to open as soon as it's created, set it to `true` :)

Comment: @Rookian: Try the updated answer...looks like the `load` behavior changed since I last looked, the updated answer should work for you.

Comment: hm it does not work too, the mask occurs a short time and then the requested page is shown without the overlay. So only the pure html is shown as if javascript is disabled.

Comment: @Rookian: you need to prevent the default behavior of the link. `.live('click', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); ... }`

Comment: @Rookian: I updated the code and demo to prevent opening (though if you don't need the url, just use `href="#"` instead).

Comment: it does not work, now 2 standard http requests were send. Before without the preventDefault function 1 ajax requests and 1 http request were send. I used Fiddler for tracing.

Answer (score 2):

Now it works fine. For all of those who has the same trouble like me here is the code ;)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // safe the overlay element in a global variable
    var overlayElem;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        // register the click event for ajax load and page load
        $("a[rel]").live('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // save overlay
            overlayElem = $(this); 

            // load overlay
            $(this).overlay({
                mask: '#3B5872',
                effect: 'apple',
                api: true,
                load: true,
                onBeforeLoad: function () {
                    var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");
                    wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
                }
            });
        });
    });

    // send form data via ajax
    function ajaxFormRequest(form, callback, format) {
        $.ajax({
            url: form.action,
            type: form.method,
            dataType: format,
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            success: callback
        });
    }
    // close the overlay and update the table 
    function update_grid(result) {
        overlayElem.overlay().close();
        $("#gridcontainer").html(result);
    }

</script>
```